# Tooltip stops working after sorting order of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I've got a list of elements that can be re-ordered by price or pax in ascending / descending order using this javascript that I found on stackoverflow:

```
var priceAscending = false;
var ratingAscending = true;

$('.container').on('click','.sortbyprice',function(){
ratingAscending = true;
var sorted = $('.listings').sort(function(a,b){
    return (priceAscending ==
           (convertToNumber($(a).find('span').html()) < 
            convertToNumber($(b).find('span').html()))) ? 1 : -1;
});
priceAscending = priceAscending ? false : true;

$('.results').html(sorted);
})
$('.container').on('click','.sortbypax',function(){ 
priceAscending = true;
var sorted = $('.listings').sort(function(a,b){
    return (ratingAscending ==
           (parseFloat($(a).find('.pax').html()) < 
            parseFloat($(b).find('.pax').html()))) ? 1 : -1;
});
ratingAscending = ratingAscending ? false : true;

$('.results').html(sorted);
});

var convertToNumber = function(value){
 return parseFloat(value.replace('$',''));
}
```

I'm not sure how well the code above is written (because I think the problem lies here) but then again I am no expert with javascript so I wouldn't know.

Then I've also got the [Tooltipster](https://github.com/iamceege/tooltipster) plugin to obviously show tooltips.

Now please see my [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6pdggn8t/)

**THE ISSUE:**

1) Before clicking on **SORT BY PRICE** or **SORT BY PAX**, please hover your mouse over the smaller numbers below the price to see their tooltip appear.

2) Now click on either **SORT BY PRICE** or **SORT BY PAX** and then try hover your mouse over the small number again. You'll notice that the tooltip doesn't work anymore.

If you refresh the page or press RUN in Js Fiddle, then the tooltips will work until you SORT them again.

Why is this?

Before using the Tooltipster plugin, I was actually using the [MiniTip](http://goldfirestudios.com/blog/81/miniTip-jQuery-Plugin) plugin but when I ran into the issue above (yes, the exact same issue happened with this plugin too) I decided to use another plugin (Tooltipster) because I thought maybe there was some sort of conflict with MiniTip. It seems like the issue probably lies with the **sorting** javascript code?

Comment: The element is definitely not responsive to hover after the sort (your brower's dev tools will highlight this).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not surprising that the tooltip plugin loses elements when the HTML is overwritten.

Instead of this:

```
$('.results').html(sorted);
```

… do this:

```
$('.results').append(sorted);
```

That will move the elements into the correct order without overwriting them.

Despite its name, when you call `append()` with an existing element, it gets moved instead of added. But when you call `html()`, you're overwriting what's already there. The tooltip plugin works on existing elements, and it therefore loses them when they get overwritten

Also, you can simplify this:

```
priceAscending = priceAscending ? false : true;
```

… to this:

```
priceAscending = !priceAscending;
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9wh6cveq/1)

Comment: Great stuff! Works like a beauty! I was actually looking at $('.results').html(sorted); as the suspect but because I'm javascript-retarded, that's the only thing I could do... Look at it!! lol! What's the difference between this and appendto code?

Comment: Turns out I was over-thinking it.  You don't need `each()`.  See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks Rick, appreciate your extended support on the matter